# What is the default cell border style and width?

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA - What is the default cell border style and width?
If you can you supply the actual `BorderAround.(LineStyle|Weight|ColorIndex|Color)` values **OR**
supply the VBA code to get the values from a default cell please?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: ```rng.BorderAround.LineStyle = xlContinuous```
```rng.BorderAround.Weight = xlThin```
```rng.BorderAround.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic```

Comment: ```Debug.Print rng.BorderAround.LineStyle```
```Debug.Print rng.BorderAround.Weigth```
```Debug.Print rng.BorderAround.ColorIndex```

Answer (score 2):

The default for a newly opened worksheet is for all cells to have the `LineStyle:=xlLineStyleNone`, and thus not to **have** `Weight`, `ColorIndex`, `Color`, or `ThemeColor`.  (Incidentally, `ColorIndex`, `Color`, and `ThemeColor` are all mutually exclusive.  You can only specify one of them, and the others will change to match.  The same rule applies for `LineStyle` and `Weight`, where setting `Weight` will change `LineStyle` to `xlContinuous`)

If you want the default for when you hit the "Add Border" button, then that is `Weight:=xlThin` and `ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic` (*normally* Black, but this can vary with the Style you have applied to Office)

The values will be stored in the `Range.Borders` property.  For example, the following will get values for the Top border of the `ActiveCell`:

```
With ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    Debug.Print "LineStyle:=" & .LineStyle
    Debug.Print "Weight:=" & .Weight
    Debug.Print "ColorIndex:=" & .ColorIndex
    Debug.Print "Color:=" & .Color
End With
```

Since `LineStyle` and `Weight` are Enumerated Values, you may need to then look them up in the [`xlLineStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllinestyle) or [`xlBorderWeight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlborderweight) enumeration tables.

(Technically, [`xlColorIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolorindex) also has an enumeration table, but it only contains 2 "special" ColorIndex values.  For a better lookup, you need something [less official](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm#colorindex))

If you want to surround a Range in a default border, then you just need to use `Range.BordersAround(ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic)`, since [`LineStyle` and `Weight` will default to Default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.BorderAround#remarks)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying it out now.